# Real root of $x(x+t)^2-4=0$ $\ge$ greatest real root of $4x^6-6x^4+4t^3x^3+t^6-3t^4=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a problem that I can not solve although I know that the statement is true.

For all  $t\ge0$ the real root of $x(x+t)^2-4=0$ is greater than or equal to the largest real root of $4x^6-6x^4+4t^3x^3+t^6-3t^4=0$. Does anyone have some idea to solve this problem?

Comment: are you sure that you have made no typo?

Comment: Yes I do. An easy way to see it: you can check this graphically.

Comment: "Checking it graphically" pretty much constitutes a proof: Show that $x(x+t)^2-4$ is still negative at a value such that the other polynomial is guaranteed to be positive there and everywhere larger.

Comment: Not really I think. For example the difficult inequality proposed by @Andreas $$\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{3}\geq\sqrt{\frac{a^4+b^4+c^4}{3}}$$  for non-negative with the constraint $ (a + b) (a + c) (b + c) = 8 $ can be easily verified graphically but this is not what is being asked.

Comment: Equivalence inequaty is $(t^3+2x^3)^2/(t^4+2x^4)>3$